# Effect of magnetic anneal vs regular anneal in steel electromagnet core

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

I am building an electromagnet with a 1018 core. I have performed careful FEA on this part and it is important to me that the experimental results closely match the FEA predictions. Since there is a fair amount of cold-working in my design, I realize that I will need to anneal the material (post-machining) to restore the grain structure.

My question is as follows - how much of a difference (in permeability for example) should I expect to see standard annealing vs magnetic annealing?

I expect the difference will likely be relatively small given that I am using plain 1018 steel rather than using some exotic permalloy or supermalloy materials.

Also in my design I do not have much of an *easy axis* that I would need/want to tune (something I understand that magnetic annealing can provide).